# FOSUserBundle add login to homepage

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I'm trying to add the FOSUserBundle login form to the homepage, it's all set up and working correctly on the /login page. I've overridden the layout to my site layout, with no issues. Everything is working as it should, but:

Using twig templating I can't display it on the homepage. Every level is extended to base.html.twig in the /app/Resources/views/ directory. Is there something I'm missing? I assumed as it works correctly in /login I possibly have a route file I need to alter.

using: orm, yml, twig.

What would be best practice for achieving this goal?

Regards.

bundle:

login.html.twig:

```
{% extends "UserBundle::layout.html.twig" %}

{% block fos_user_content %}{# form stuff here #}{% endblock fos_user_content %}
```

layout.html.twig:

```
{% extends '::base.html.twig' %}

{% block login %}
    {{ block('fos_user_content') }}
{% endblock login %}
```

app:

base.html.twig:

```
{% block login %}{% endblock login %}
```

Comment: Do I need to create a controller to create an instance of the form, and display it? If so how could I achieve this?